# Read-write property in interface VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, properties, interface

I would like to write an interface class and use it like this

```
public Interface IFunction
  property name as string
end interface

public class ModelFunction
   implements IFunction

  public property name as string

  public sub new()

end class
```

*EDIT(deleted following sentence for being noob, thanks @damien_the_unbeliever for pointing this out):But this is not possible to get because a property in an vb.net interface has to be readonly or writeonly (as far as i get it)*

I have now written this but seems a little wrong:

```
public Interface IFunction
  Readlonly property getName() as string
  writeonly property writeName() as string
end interface

public class ModelFunction
 implements IFunction

 ....
end class
```

Anyone have a better solution for this? or can help me out with properties in an Interface class. Have read some articles here on stackoverflow but none of them point me in the right direction.

Comment: "a property in an vb.net interface has to be readonly or writeonly" - really?

Comment: The only problem in your original code is the missing `Implements IFunction.name` on his property in the class, it should read: `public property name as string Implements IFunction.name`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
Public Class Class1
    Implements Thing

    Property Gary As Int32 Implements Thing.Gary
        Get
            Return 10
        End Get
        Set(value As Int32)

        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Interface Thing
    Property Gary As Int32
End Interface
```

There's even an example on the documentation page for [`Interface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e2e18x.aspx):

```
Interface IAsset
    Event ComittedChange(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Property Division() As String 
    Function GetID() As Integer 
End Interface
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this but appereantly make a mistake somewhere. Works good now. Thank you very much